# The equation $x-\sin x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, numerical-methods

If we have the equation $x-\sin x=0$, then we can trivially or numerically find the solution to be $x=0$. However, I rearrange the equation algebraically and get $$\frac{\sin x}x=1.$$ 
If I plug $x=0$ into $\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}x$, I don't get a $1$; it's actually undefined.

(And yes, I know, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}x=1$. Not sure if this helps though.)

Comment: You divided by zero. The algebraic manipulation is not valid if $x = 0$...

Comment: $x-\sin x=0$ is not the same as $\sin x/x=1$.

Comment: "What gives" is that you divided by $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @le gâteau au fromage Just a small suggestion for your french motto, you should rather write: "Non, je ne parle pas couramment le français. Mais tous les jours, j'étudie un peu de cette langue !" Anyway: bravo!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should write since you divide by $x$ which it vanishes at $0$:

$$\sin x-x=0\iff \left(\frac{\sin x}x=1\right)\lor \left(x=0\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Your equation should be:

$$x = \sin x$$

Only solution occurs is $x = 0$.

Comment: +1 If you graph $x$ versus $\sin x$ notice that both graphs have a value of $0$ and a slope of $1$ where $x=0$. As x moves away from $0$, $x$, the first graph, becomes a $45^\circ$ line and $\sin x$ becomes less steep, meaning that $\sin x$ diverges away from $x$.

Comment: Meaning that $\sin x$ and $x$ can only ever be equal when $x=0$

Answer (score 2):

First define $f(x) = x - \sin(x)$ and note that $f(0) = 0 - \sin(0) = 0$. Now, consider $x>0$. Then $f'(x) = 1 - \cos(x) \geq 0$ and so $f(x) \geq 0$. Also note that $$x - \sin(x) \geq \frac{x^3}6 - \frac{x^5}{120} \geq \frac{x^3}6 - \frac{x^3}{120} = \frac{19x^3}{120} > 0,$$ for all $x \in (0,1].$ Then, since $f$ is non-decreasing, $f(x) \geq f(1) > 0$, $\forall x \in (1, \infty)$. The other case for $x<0$ is similar.

Comment: Those are factorials, right?

Comment: @abeissu, yes indeed. I sometimes forget when I'm writing quickly.

Comment: @ChrisK I took the liberty to improve the format of your answer, just so it is a little easier to read. The content, however, was unchanged. I hope that is okay with you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged "precalculus" i'll do my best to give a simple answer. The first equation is not "equivalent" to the second equation, in the sense that they dont have the same set of solutions. This appears strange to you, because you got to the second one by doing simple algebraic manipulations to the first. And you ask the question: "What gives?".

The answer is: If you believe that one equation is equivalent to the other the you should prove it (note that this is how real math is done, not like in school where you are simply taught to manipulate variables). In this case, as you found out, this is not possible since in the first eqn 0 is obviously a solution, and the other is not defined at that point. So the real lesson here is (not what you expected i guess) that manipulating equations doesn't necessarily get you equivalent equations. In this case you devided by a quantity that you then set equal to zero. Obviously this is trouble...

The last answer given by Sami Ben Romdhane is also correct but very short and i thought i would elaborate a bit more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The comment to my question by @Tbongers answered it perfectly. Also, I just asked a random precalculus question. This does not imply that I am a precalculus student, if that's what you were thinking, as you said "this is how real math is done, not in school where you are simply taught to manipulate variables". If you look at my question history via my profile, you will see that the majority of my questions concern graduate PDE theory.

Comment: yep sorry didnt check out your profile. Thought i was talking to a pre calc student. cheers!